# Designing a PID control with plant controlled using relays

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, constant-current, pid-controller, latching-relay

I am working on a project to design a Controlled (Constant Current) DC Battery Charger.

The charger has a variable transformer (Plant). The output of which is fed to the batteries to charge them via a rectifier circuit.

The winding of the variable transformer(Autotransformer) is controlled via a Motor (Fixed RPM synchronous motor with only two relays as input for forward and backward rotation). The motor changes the number of windings of the transformer, eventually controlling the output voltage and thus maintaining a constant current through the batteries.

Also, Steady-state error is negotiable, and the user can change it as per requirements.
Schematic attached below.
[image: Schematic for Closed Loop Controller]
**The plant is controlled via two relays ( forward and backward motion of the motor, FIXED RPM). Therefore only whether to stop or run the motor in forward or backward direction (for a given duration) can be controlled** The sensor is assumed ideal, and therefore, its dynamics are ignored.

My goal is to design and tune a PID controller for this plant. And embed this logic into a micro-controller for its implementation (Arduino).

I have a few questions in mind and require your assistance for the same.

1. Can this system be controlled using a PID method?
2. Is it better to have a PID control, rather than having a standard error based decision?
   E.g. I can measure the output current, compare it with the set value and decide where the motor has to move based on intuition.
3. I am not able to model the system, assistance appreciated.

If I have missed anything, please let me know. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since you have relays that switch the motor direction you might run into problems by switching them too many times if you use a text-book PID. Do you have any idea/references on how dynamical the plant and load are? If they don't show much dynamic behavior, during startup you could just ramp up the motor until you are close to the desired current and then start using a P controller for regulation, if your control \$u \sim \frac{dV_{peak}}{dt} \sim \frac{dI}{dt} \$ then you won't need an integral in the control such that the error tends to zero.

Comment: There's no issue with the frequent switching as such. I am using SSRs believe they can handle it. I am not sure about the plant dynamics, but after having a large number of observations, I can tell that **in the variable transformer, voltage increases/decreases linearly with time across the load when the motor rotates. The load shows a V-I characteristic like a diode in forward bias** ( Current remains almost nil up to a certain voltage applied and after the breakdown shoots up with even a slight change in voltage)

Comment: I'm not sure what is the best dynamical model for a battery, maybe modelling it as a capacitor or a nonlinear capacitor might be enough to get you some simulations done. That being said, I don't thing the PID will be of much help, since the transformer changes  its voltage up and down at a constant rate and the load might not be that dynamic (just some charging capacitor/battery). You should check Bang-bang control, that will probably be simpler and give you a good enough result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps.

Comment: You missed inertia of the motor , unless you use the e-brake mode. Then there are   EMI possibilities. LdI/dt=V. To model it define the transfer function of each stage and effects of delay with hysteresis.

Comment: You can also have an *inner* PID loop for the motor and an *outer* PID loop for the transformer / current. This helps because, you can model and design them in stages which will simplify things. You will also get two sets of PID gains and this gives additional freedom for tuning.

Comment: @AJN What would be the point of having one, or even two, PID? The motor rotates at a constant speed the tap of the autotransformer, you can't control the speed of the motor. And having the single PID would not also help much, the amplitude of the control \$u\$ does not affect anything in the system, it would be better to keep it simple and use the Bang-bang, to have the PID you would need to output a slow PWM or something to the relay (which would be slower and lead to more or less the same result), so it would be better to just turn it on/off accordingly.

Comment: @jDAQ My thought process --> By having an inner loop with a high bandwidth, the transformer current loop can be *assumed* to have a linear control mechanism. Having a linear design strategy also allows for calculating the the robustness of the controller in terms of the Gain and Phase margins (for the outer loop). Inner loop can still remain bang-bang.

Shouldn't there be a D feedback somewhere since the system contains a subsystem (the motor) with *inertia* ? 

Even if the PID controller is used, *it can be converted to use a bang-bang actuator with a simple threshold logic*.

Comment: Disregard some of my previous comments. I assumed the motor dynamics are similar to that of the induction motor. If the motor is *guaranteed* to be in lock step with the AC input (and doesn't overshoot once relay is cut off), then multiple loops are not required.

Comment: @jDAQ After observing a lot. I seem that the carbon brush on the autotransformer runs a bit blunt creating a lot of friction. Thus I feel inertia should not be a problem as such. The RPMs are quite slow (the motor takes about 28 seconds to go from 0 to full). Therefore would it be a fine to neglect its dynamics and inertia?.
In that case what's better a Bang Bang or a PID control as suggested earlier?

Comment: When you say *"motor takes about 28 seconds to go from 0 to full"*, Do you mean full speed or one full rotation ?

Comment: One full rotation of the winding (0 Volts to Max Volts)